# PHP set multiple variables from a function

Tags: php, function

I am trying to set three variables from a test function.

Here's my code so far:

```
function test()
{
    $x = 1;
    $y = 2;
    $z = 3; 


}

test();

# should print '1', '2', and '3'
echo $x; 
echo $y;
echo $z;
```

Comment: you would have to make your variable global, or return the values from the function in the form of an array.

Comment: What's with all the downvotes?

Comment: Maybe because OP has made no effort to search for the answer... it's asked here on almost a daily basis

Comment: Yeah strange all the answers bar 1 have downvotes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the variables as global? Like:

```
function test()
{
    global $x, $y, $z;
    $x = 1;
    $y = 2;
    $z = 3; 
}
```

Comment: Picked this answer for its simpleness

Comment: thnx, simple question simple answer :)

Comment: This answer is incorrect tho, as a global var is never returned, and it's really poor programming to go this route...

Comment: well, this works http://codepad.viper-7.com/iIzWP7 the variables don't have to be returned... going with an array as you suggested is not the best solution too...

Comment: btw @Jakub, it is based on a example featured on http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php in `Example #1 Using global` so I suggest that you notify the php.net team about their poor programming too...

Answer (score 4):

Just return an object or an array (array is probably the way to go):

```
function test(){
   $data = array(
     'x' => 1,
     'y' => 2,
     'z' => 3
   );

   return $data;

}

print_r( test() );
```

or call each value:

```
echo $data['x'];
...
```

Comment: or `print_r($data)` to print out all the variables from the output array

Comment: oh yes ... i didn't see that you already put that there. sorry

Answer (score 3):

There'd be 3 easy-to-apply options in this case. One would be to pass the variables by reference, in stead of by value. The other would be to return an array. Another option would be to use global variables.
Here's an example of both:

### By reference

```
<?php
function example (&$x, &$y, &$z)
{
    $x = 1;
    $y = 2;
    $z = 3;
}
?>
```

Passing a variable by reference means that you're passing the actual variable (the space allocated for it in the computer's memory), in stead of by value (just passing the value to the function) as usual.
So when you pass a variable by reference (which the `&` character does), and you manipulate the value, the value of the original variable gets changed as well.

### Returning an array

```
<?php
function example ($x, $y, $z)
{
    $arr['x'] = 1;
    $arr['y'] = 2;
    $arr['z'] = 3;

    return $arr;
}
?>
```

Now you can access the values by using `$arr['x'];`, `$arr['y'];` and `$arr['z'];`.

### Global variables

```
<?php
$x = 0;
$y = 0;
$z = 0;

function example ()
{
    global $x, $y, $z;

    $x = 1;
    $y = 2;
    $z = 3;
}
?>
```

Comment: Reference worked perfect for my use case. Thanks for the different explanations.

Answer (score 2):

options:

use references:

```
function test(&$x, &$y, &$z) {
    $x = 1;
    $y = 2;
    $z = 3;
}
```

or return an array and use [extract](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php):

```
function test() {
    return array(
        'x' => 1,
        'y' => 2,
        'z' => 3
    );
}

extract(test());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function func ()
{
    return array (
        'x' => 1,
        'y' => 3,
        'z' => 42
    );
}


extract (func ());

echo $x, $y, $z;
```

or

```
function func ()
{
    return array (
         1,
         3,
         42
    );
}

list ($x, $y, $z) = func ();
```